# KDB+ / Q How to create a namespace within a function

Tags: kdb

I tried to build a function that takes in the name of namespace, a list of key, and a list of value. However, the function unable to read the key and value of the namespace.

For example:

```
q) makens:{[ns,keylist,valuelist] temp_ns: x.keylist.valuelist; set[.ns;temp_ns]}
q) makens:[`hello;`age`gender;`10 "M"]
```

I'm expecting my output to be:

```
q) .hello
         | ::
age      | `10
gender   | "M"
```

Instead, the namespace doesn't work and when I use set at the end, it doesn't read `.ns` as the input, i.e.:

```
q) makens:[`hello;`age`gender;`10 "M"]
q) .hello
'.hello
  [3]  .hello
       ^
q) .ns
`10`M
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
q)makens:{[ns;keylist;valuelist](` sv `,ns) upsert ((`,keylist)!(::),valuelist)};
q)makens[`hello;`age`gender;`10,"M"]
`.hello
q).hello
      | ::
age   | `10
gender| "M"
```